# Update parent of Maven project using maven plugin

Tags: maven

Current i have maven project, it has one parent defined in its pom.

I want to update parent of project. I am able to update version of parent using following command:

```
mvn versions:update-parent -DallowSnapshots=true -DparentVersion=[4.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

How do i update artifactID for parent?

Comment: Simply edit the pom file...?

Comment: I have over 60 to 70 projects, looking for some plugin

Comment: You have changed the artifactId ? If yes I would write a script for such a number of files...(linux: sed is your friend ;-))

Comment: yeah tried sed it updates artifactid but above command works only if version for parent exists. Let me check other ways